# Getting a 403 Forbidden Error for Youtube Data API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am getting a 403 forbidden error when making an API call to the YouTube Data API.

I have tried to generate different types of keys (Web Browser, Server, etc.).  The key is unrestricted.  I have tried making the call from a server and from postman for Chrome.  The request URL and response is below.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=surfing&key={api-key}`

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "Forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

Here are the headers:

```
alt-svc →quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
cache-control →private, max-age=0
content-encoding →gzip
content-length →118
content-type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
date →Tue, 10 Jul 2018 15:00:27 GMT
expires →Tue, 10 Jul 2018 15:00:27 GMT
server →GSE
status →403
vary →Origin, X-Origin
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block
```

Comment: Verify you've enabled the YouTube Data API v3 service for this key in your Google Developers console.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a [Core API error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain) as what specified in the Youtube API documentation.

> Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.

You can check the step by step guide provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro). You will bump with the step on how to properly acquire user [authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

> Intended for developers who want to write applications that interact
>   with YouTube. It explains basic concepts of YouTube and of the API
>   itself. It also provides an overview of the different functions that
>   the API supports.

Comment: This answer was not helpful.  We have gone through all the correct steps for generating an api key as outlined in the documentation.

Comment: There is public data available which should not require authorization, just API_KEY added to the request url.

Answer (score 1):

These types of error related to YouTube APIs core apis errors

> Core API errors
>
> forbidden (403) : Access forbidden :The request may not be properly
> authorized.
>
> quotaExceeded (403) : quotaExceeded : The request cannot be
> completed because you have exceeded your quota.

You can try adding OAuth using this documentation on YouTube Data API Overview as a guide.

> If your application will use any API methods that require user
> authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement
> OAuth 2.0 authorization.

If you are getting the same error then , verify the YouTube Data API v3 service enabled for this key in your [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/apis/library).

```
URL : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=surfing&key={API_KEY}

{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/vxoFCv0dm4WdeKtXnUk7GXCJeao\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "IN",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Amykv1hEk5vzuqlcAS8z2BEptrU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "CWYDxh7QD34"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-09-02T16:52:33.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCblfuW_4rakIf2h6aqANefA",
    "title": "Best surfing action from Red Bull Cape Fear 2014",
    "description": "Click for the FULL EVENT: http://www.redbullcapefear.com/ The southern tip of Sydney Australia is home to one of the most treacherous waves on the planet: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWYDxh7QD34/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWYDxh7QD34/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWYDxh7QD34/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Red Bull",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with multiple api-keys and I didn't hit an issue.

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search\?part\=snippet\&maxResults\=1\&q\=surfing\&key\={api-key}
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/r9B676JRBM0twgG6dy2MZT_1KnQ\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/E8GZG_CZfJeaVF75eZYmJHnGe0c\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "rj7xMBxd5iY"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-11-12T11:09:52.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCiiFGfvlKvX3uzMovO3unaw",
    "title": "BIG WAVE SURFING COMPILATION 2017",
    "description": "BIG WAVE SURFING COMPILATION 2017 ** REVISED **AMAZING FOOTAGE ** WITH 60-100FT- HUGE SURF Please Subscribe if You Would like to see More ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rj7xMBxd5iY/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rj7xMBxd5iY/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rj7xMBxd5iY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Absolutely Flawless",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and it is resolved by enabling the 'YouTube Data API v3' from the API Library