# Getting error 403 "forbidden" in Youtube Data API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am getting error 403 in response after applying restriction on my API key with the package name and signing key. I extract my SHA 1 key from singing report option in the android studio and this key is working fine in my firebase console. When I am removing the restriction from API key in google cloud platform console it works. Do I need to put restriction to avoid any theft on it? If yes, then what am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), 403 error means that the access is forbidden and the request may not be properly authorized. You may use OAuth by following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro).

> If your application will use any API methods that require user authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization.

Here are some references which might also help:

- [Getting a 403 Forbidden Error for Youtube Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268669/getting-a-403-forbidden-error-for-youtube-data-api)
- [Error 403 Forbidden whith Youtube API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411632/error-403-forbidden-whith-youtube-api-v3)
- [youtube data api intermittently throw access forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498808/youtube-data-api-intermittently-throw-access-forbidden?noredirect=1#comment72261354_42498808)